# - に詰まる meaning and use

Tags: translation

in the sentence

お前は思考に詰まるとすぐこれだ.

I know that 言葉に詰まる means to be at loss of words

Does 思考に詰まる mean to stop thinking?

thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means "to have a momentary brain freeze" but it is not of the icecream kind.

Comment: Thank you!!
I wasn't sure between that or the opposite "to over think"